# How would I delete an array of ids/objects in Rails from my DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, rails-activerecord

I understand one could do something like `Model.destroy_all(status: "inactive")`. I wish my case were this simple, but I can't do it like that. I have an encrypted string column that maps to an array of integers via the attr_encrypted gem which makes this cumbersome.

Basically, I have an array like this: `array = [object1, object2, object3, object4]` where each object is model object.

I want to be able to do something like `Model.destroy_all(array)` or `Model.delete_all(array)`, but I am unable to do this.

I even tried the following: `Model.destroy_all(array.map(&:id))` and `Model.delete_all(array.map(&:id))` and I couldn't successfully delete them.

I want to be as efficient as possible and I don't think `array.map(&:destroy)` or `array.map(&:delete)` would be efficient as I'd get `N` calls. Should I do that and wrap it in a transaction? Is there a better way?

**Update: I figured it out and included an answer down below.**

Comment: You can do `Model.destroy_all(id: array.map(&:id))`. I believe it better optimized compared to `Model.destroy(array)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, this is silly. Turns out I could just do:

`Model.delete(array)` or `Model.destroy(array)` where the first one doesn't do any of the callbacks and is definitely much faster, whereas the other one instantiates and performs all the callbacks.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to call `destroy_all` you may as well loop through them yourself since that is what the method does itself (in order to process any callbacks).

If you're going to delete them though then this should work:

```
Model.where(id: array.map(&:id)).delete_all
```

Comment: Similarly but using `destroy`, you can do too: `Model.where(id: array.map(&:id)).destroy_all`